# playing mp3 files in firefox

Tags: firefox, mp3, jplayer

Can anyone suggest me webplayer which can play MP3 files in Firefox browser?
I tried jPlayer, however it needs ogg files. I tried converting MP3 to OGA using FFMPEG, however, even the generated file is not being played in JPlayer. 
Is there any alternate player which can play MP3 files in Firefox. 
I don't want to use Flash.

Comment: Why not let the user download and decide which application works best?

Comment: jplayes does actually support mp3, mp4 (AAC/H.264), ogg (Vorbis/Theora), webm (Vorbis/VP8), wav

Comment: @sarnold I am developing a site wherein, user can upload their music and play it online.

Comment: @Teejay Can you explain more about it..

Comment: @RaoG The copyright on that site sounds....illegal

Comment: @RaoG It's stated on the jplayer official page

Answer (score 1):

> ..alternate player which can play MP3 files in Firefox.

Combine these 3 for an answer.

- [Java Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for the ability to play audio.
- The MP3 plug-in SPI of JMF, to supply support for MP3, which Java Sound does not support by default.
- Applet - to embed that ability in a web page.

### Note

I am pretty sure there are easy ways to embed sound in web pages that does not require Java, or requires plug-ins that have higher usage (like Flash). If there is not something custom you wish to do, I recommend investigating alternatives.

Comment: It all seems to be java based solution, I will have to create an Applet for it, which I don't want. Isn't there any other alterative ?

Comment: I took the 'java' tag to be literal.  See the update to answer.  And please choose tags more carefully in future.

Comment: I thought I retagged it fairly quickly. Not quickly enough looks like! :-)

Comment: @maksimov  Thanks for re-tagging.  Might save others a few moments.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks I would take care in future about tagging.